# Do the CP rewards stack when earned with different characters?

Tags: danmachi-memoria-freese

Do the CP rewards stack with the same rewards earned from different characters?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

For example, if you get a stat bonus from leveling up the CP of a given character with Bell, and then another with Lefiya, that character will receive the bonus twice.